# UnsupportedOperationException in vert.x/netty fileupload

Tags: netty, vert.x

I am trying to upload a file using vert.x[3.9.8] but for large files [1GB+] i keep getting below error.The file is being uploaded correctly. Whats the issue i am running into.
Is this a Netty version clash with Vert.x?

```
[2022-09-05 14:40:30 +0530][io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl] SEVERE: Unhandled exception 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.NettyFileUpload.definedLength(NettyFileUpload.java:179)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.loadDataMultipartOptimized(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:1188)
```

```
    public void helidonToVertxTest(TestContext testContext) {
                Async fileSentAsync = testContext.async();
                Async fileReceivedAsync = testContext.async();
                Router router = Router.router(vertx);
                router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
                router.post("/api/upload").handler(routingContext -> {
                    System.out.println("File/s has been received.");
                    routingContext.response().end();
                    testContext.assertEquals(1, routingContext.fileUploads().size());
                    Iterator<FileUpload> iterator = routingContext.fileUploads().iterator();
                    FileUpload artifact = iterator.next();
                    Path savedArtifactsPath = Paths.get(artifact.uploadedFileName());
                    System.out.println("Uploaded file is "+savedArtifactsPath);
                    testContext.assertTrue(savedArtifactsPath.toFile().exists());
                    fileReceivedAsync.complete();
                });
            
                vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080, listenResult -> {
                    if (listenResult.failed()) {
                        System.out.println("Could not start HTTP server");
                        listenResult.cause().printStackTrace();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Server started");
                        Path tempFile = createTemporaryFile();
                        String filename = "C:\\Users\\ansgupgu\\Pictures\\Movies\\cp.mp4";
                        sendFileHelidonUsingMultipart(fileSentAsync, Path.of(filename));
                    }
                });
                fileSentAsync.await(60*1000);
                fileReceivedAsync.await(60*1000);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Netty 4.1.69.Final and later [calls `definedLength()`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.77.Final/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/multipart/HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java#L1188).  Vert.x 3.9.10 [changes](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/commit/bda8dd017166f9b012023621782c8c567198b4be) `definedLength()`'s implementation from `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` to an actual calculation.  So you'll want to use Vert.x 3.9.10 or later with Netty 4.1.69.Final or later.